# Want to share backup file in Django web container with Postgres database container: How to?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

EDIT 2

In fact I realized that automatic backup done today in preprod environment (nginx) by celery/dbbackup are not available in container?

I only have backup from yesterday when I use development environment (django runserver)....

---

EDIT 1

change docker-compose accordingly
backup_volume is mounted
I can not found where in local but if I cnnect to the db container and run \i 'path/to/file.psql' it works

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-01-19T14:37:55Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "cafe_tropical",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.4",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "backup_volume"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/cafe_tropical_backup_volume/_data",
        "Name": "cafe_tropical_backup_volume",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

---

I have a Django app on Docker with web container where automatics backups are stored and another postgresql database container.

I want to be able to restore postgresql database using \i 'path\to\backup.psql' in a psql shell but it failed because file is not found

```
db_preprod=# \i '/usr/src/app/backup/backup_2021-01-19_1336.psql'
/usr/src/app/backup/backup_2021-01-19_1336.psql: No such file or directory
```

I also tryed to copy with docker cp but not works:

```
docker cp web:/usr/src/ap/backup/backup_2021-01-19_1336.psql db:/.
copying between containers is not supported
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: web
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        restart: always
        command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
            - backup_volume:/usr/src/app/backup         <-- added volume
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000/"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 50         
          
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
            - backup_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/backup  <-- added volume
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod.db
   
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build: ./nginx
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        ports:
            - 1340:80
        depends_on:
            web:
                condition: service_healthy

volumes:
    postgres_data:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    backup_volume:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use volumes. Both containers mount the same path. Django outputs the dump and then psql gets it. But why does it work like this? Shouldn't you be able to output and restore from either django or postgres?

Comment: thanks for replying. Maybe it is not the right way to do but I use django dbbackup app and Celey/Celery-beats to make automatics db backup. And it works. But you are right, the first thing I tryed to do was to 'dumpdata' but I do not knwo why it did not works and json files was incorrect and could not be use for loaddata

Comment: Sure no problem - just curious. Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#natural-keys this has helped me overcome issues like the one you had with dumpdata